# How to dynamically rename the hdf5 file from psychopy's iohub

Tags: python, yaml, psychopy

I'm using the Psychopy 1.82.01 Coder and its iohub functionality (on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS). It is working but I was wondering if there is a way to dynamically rename the hdf5 file it produces during an experiment (such that in the end, I know which participant it belongs to and two participants will get two files without overwriting one of them).
It seems to me that the filename is determined in this file: https://github.com/psychopy/psychopy/blob/df68d434973817f92e5df78786da313b35322ae8/psychopy/iohub/default_config.yaml
But is there a way to change this dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a different hdf5 file for each experiment run, then the options depend on how you are starting the ioHub process. Assuming you are using the `psychopy.iohub.launchHubServer()` function to start ioHub, then you can pass the 'experiment_code' kwarg to the function and that will be used as the hdf5 file name.

For example, if you created a script with the following code and ran it:

```
import psychopy.iohub as iohub

io = iohub.launchHubServer(experiment_code="exp_sess_1")

# your experiment code here ....
# ...

io.quit()
```

An ioHub hdf5 file called 'exp_sess_1.hdf5' will be created in the same folder as the script file.

As a side note, you do not have to save each experiment sessions data into a separate hdf5 file. The ioHub hdf5 file structure is designed to save multiple participants  / sessions data in a single file. Each time the experiment is run, a unique session code is required, and the data from each run is saved in the hdf5 file with a session id that is associated with the session code.

Comment: I am starting the iohub by extending the ioHubExperimentRuntime class, so essentially I implemented the method run and call start on an instance of my runtime class.

Why I am doing this... this might be overcautious, but I feel better to have separate files as in that case there is no way a problem in the last experiment will mess with all my data.

Comment: If you are extending the ioHubExperimentRuntime class, do you also have a "iohub_config.yaml" file in the same directory as your experiment script? 
 - If yes, then you could load the file before the iohub connection is made and change the data_store: filename: parameter to have the name you want, then save back the updated yaml file. This is probably more work and more ugly than doing the os level file renaming at the end of the experiment.

Comment: If you do not have a "iohub_config.yaml" file in the experiment dir, then you could create one prior to the iohub connection being made, and write out to it just the needed data_store: filename: setting, then close the file.when the iohub connection is created, it will pick up the iohub_config.yaml file and use the file name you provided. Again, pretty messy. So probably either switch to using the launchHubServer function, or do as Jonas suggested and rename the hdf5 file, but after the iohub server has been closed as you suggested.